# Unable to cast object of type MemberListBinding to type MemberAssignment

Tags: c#, grpc

I have a method to return data to a gRPC client. In this method I receive following error

> Unable to cast object of type MemberListBinding to type MemberAssignment

Caused by:

```
PossibleInOutZones = 
                        { 
                            Query.All<InOutZones>().Select(x => new InOutZone()
                            {
                                Id = x.ID,
                                Name = x.Name
                            })
                        },
```

Full Code:

```
public override Task<CargoesResponse> GetNotDockedCargos(Empty request, ServerCallContext context)
        {
            return Helpers.InterService.Invoke(_domain, () =>
            {
                return Task.FromResult(new CargoesResponse {
                    Cargoes =
                    {
                        Query.All<Cargos>().Select(c => new Cargo
                        {
                            c.CMR ?? "",
                            PossibleInOutZones = 
                            { 
                                Query.All<InOutZones>().Select(x => new InOutZone()
                                {
                                    Id = x.ID,
                                    Name = x.Name
                                })
                            },
                        })
                    }
                });
            });
        }
```

Anybody has a clue why this occurs?

Comment: You need to show the types of the offending assignments, `PossibleInOutZones`, `InOutZone`, etc

Answer (score 0):

Error occurs only when doing multiple .Select inside the return.
Fixed when this is extracted outside and FOR-loop is used instead of nested .Select statement